# Unhandled win32 Exception occurred in my Android ADV

Tags: eclipse, exception, android-emulator, win32exception

Help!

Every time I run any device from Android AVD it crashes, then the Visual Studio ? starts and gives the followed message.

> A unhandled win32 Exception occurred
>   in emulator.exe

followed message appears on Console

```
[2011-03-18 16:10:16 - Logcat]device not found
```

com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: device not found
    at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.setDevice(AdbHelper.java:736)
    at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:373)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Device.executeShellCommand(Device.java:284)
    at com.android.ddmuilib.logcat.LogPanel$3.run(LogPanel.java:527)

the loGcAT point these Error, I'm not sure it can help:

System(50): Failure starting core service
System(50): Failure starting core service
System(50):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
System(50):     at android.os.ServiceManagerProxy.addService(ServiceManagerNative.java:146)
System(50):     at android.os.ServiceManager.addService(ServiceManager.java:72)
System(50):     at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:162)
AndroidRuntime(50): Crash logging skipped, no checkin service

It happens whith all devices and I can't get more information, Eclipse don't returns any.

I realy dont know what to do. Help!

Comment: I also deleted the avd and recreated it. worked fine. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I hade the same issue yesterday. I managed to fix this by uninstalling the Android SDK and re-install it.

I don't know what caused the issue, and I don't want to try to reproduce it now, but I know of 2 differences between the 2 installations:
1) The first time I went directry to the AVD manager in the "Available packages" and made some updates there. In the "Third party Add-ons" there were some available packages that were still there after the installation and after "Refresh". This puzzled me and made me try a couple of times. Therefore I made a couple of redundant installations, and this may have caused some trouble.
2) The first time I used the .exe file to make the installation, while I downloaded the .zip-file for the second installation. Probably this has nothing to do with the error.

Hope this helps you! It really is an annoying problem.

Comment: Thanks Vanja, I deleted and recriated my AVDs and now it's working well.

Comment: It happened to me once more, and then I followed your procedure to delete the AVD and recreate is. That solved it this time (it didn't work last time though). So, thanks for the suggestion!